# mapbox expression to filter feature property of layer (feature id) by array of ids

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm using Mapbox GL JS 1.12.

I'm trying to selectively extrude buildings by feature id. I have successfully filtered data from the 'building-extrusion' layer in Mapbox Studio to achieve this effect. However, I'm keen to know the code way so that i don't have to manually enter a long list of ids into the input form on the UI.

Here's a way I felt is intuitive and correct to me based on what i gather from the documentation and other code snippets online.

```
     let filter=[
       "any",
       ["in", [123456, 245085, 435086], ["to-number", ["get", "id"]]],
       ['==', 'extrude', 'true']
     ]
     map.setFilter('some-buildings-3d',filter)
```

Errors:

> Error: layers.some-buildings-3d.filter[1][1]: string expected, array
> found
>
> Error: layers.fire-stations-3d.filter[1][2]: string, number, or
> boolean expected, array found

I'm using the defualt 'composite' source to add layer;

```
map.addLayer(
  {
    'id': 'some-buildings-3d',
    'source': 'composite',
    'source-layer': 'building',
    'type': 'fill-extrusion',
    'paint': {
        'fill-extrusion-color': '#aaa',
        'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.6
    }
  },labelLayerId
);
```

Rather than continuing to mindlessly trial-and-error, does anyone at StackO has experience with Mapbox expressions to filter data and know of the right approach?

Comment: Could you please create a minimal setup, to see where you are getting those error's?

Answer (score 0):

the [syntax](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#in) of `in` is:

```
["in",
    keyword: InputType (boolean, string, or number),
    input: InputType (array or string)
]: boolean
```

i think you need `any`.

```
[
  "any",
  ["in", 123456, ["to-number", ["get", "id"]]],
  ["in", 245085, ["to-number", ["get", "id"]]],
  ["in", 435086, ["to-number", ["get", "id"]]],
]
```